# How can I create a new CALayer from a Presentation Layer?

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

I'm capturing a frame of an animated view, and I'd like to use this to create a new `CALayer` to add to a view. This is the code I have at the moment but nothing is appearing;

`let screenshot = animatedView.layer.presentation()
let newLayer = CALayer.init(layer: screenshot)
self.view.layer.addSublayer(newLayer)`

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

`presentation()` just returns a copy of a `layer` as it's being presented on screen.

Try it like this:

```
if let screenshot = animatedView.layer.presentation() {
    let modelLayer = CALayer(layer: screenshot)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(modelLayer)
}
```

You could also make sure the `layer` is laid out first before you call `presentation()`

```
animatedView.layer.setNeedsLayout()
```

**EDIT:** My mistake - I guess a copy can't be added as a sublayer. Edited code above to include a proper instantiation of a CALayer from a presentation copy.

Comment: thanks, i tried that code but i got this error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidTree', reason: 'expecting model layer not copy: <CALayer: 0x600000be64a0>'`

Comment: My bad, edited code above. Make sure you're instantiating your modelLayer correctly.

Comment: still returning a blank layer for me, but thankyou for your help :)

Comment: Hmm. Are you animating `animatedView` or are you animating `animatedView.layer`? For the former, I don't think taking `presentation()` of the view's layer will work (you'd need to get the `ImageContext` for that). Let me know if that's the case.

Comment: yeah i've ended up using `ImageContext` - appreciate your insight though!